# SQLAlchemy long running script: User was holding a relation lock for too long

Tags: python, postgresql, session, transactions, sqlalchemy

I have an SQLAlchemy session in a script. The script is running for a long time, and it only fetches data from database, never updates or inserts.

I get quite a lot of errors like

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (TransactionRollbackError) terminating connection due to conflict with recovery
DETAIL:  User was holding a relation lock for too long.
```

The way I understand it, SQLAlchemy creates a transaction with the first select issued, and then reuses it. As my script may run for about an hour, it is very likely that a conflict comes up during the lifetime of that transaction.

To get rid of the error, I could use autocommit in te deprecated mode (without doing anything more), but this is explicitly discouraged by the documentation.

What is the right way to deal with the error? Can I use ORM queries without transactions at all?

Comment: Usually these kind of issues are dealed by batching the work to smaller batches. E.g. commit/rollback after each 1000 objects to signal the database you are done with the data and you do not care if the contents changes or not. So this sounds more like the script design itself could be improved.

Comment: You can always make SQLAlchemy objects reuseable even after the transaction is closed with an option and thus have data copy in memory.

Comment: are you running it along with streaming replication?..

Comment: @BartoszMarcinkowski so that is the source of error. "Increasing max_standby_archive_delay and max_standby_streaming_delay
would be helpful to make the query complete. Please see the following manual for details." (c) read the http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/hot-standby.html#HOT-STANDBY-CONFLICT

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change PostgreSQL configuration; I need my script to work with current replication setup.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up closing the session after (almost) every select, like

```
session.query(Foo).all()
session.close()
```

since I do not use autocommit, a new transaction is automatically opened.

Comment: That's the right way to do it. The transaction starts regardless of what query is sent. So you need to commit / close it even though you only read from the database.