# Psycog2 terminating connection due to conflict with recovery DETAIL: User was holding a relation lock for too long

Tags: python, database, postgresql, runtime-error

I am using python to query through a really huge PG database. I used the server-side cursor and unfortunately when I run into 170000+ rows, it gives me the error:

> psycopg2.extensions.TransactionRollbackError: terminating connection
>   due to conflict with recovery DETAIL:  User was holding a relation
>   lock for too long. HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect
>   to the database and repeat your command. server closed the connection
>   unexpectedly  This probably means the server terminated abnormally
>     before or while processing the request.

Here is a similar issue but it doesn't solve my confusion at all as I am fairly new to coding and psycog2. [the sqlalchemy error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097787/sqlalchemy-long-running-script-user-was-holding-a-relation-lock-for-too-long). Could anyone suggest a solution and code? Many thanks!

```
conn=pg.connect(host="XXX",database="XXX", user="XXX", password="XXX")
cur = conn.cursor('my_cursor')

cur.execute("select XX,XXX from XXXX")
count = 0
data = []

while True:
  rows = cur.fetchmany(100)
  if not rows:
    break

  for id, xml in rows:

    count += 1
    if count % 5000 == 0:
        print('processing The %d record' % count)
    data.append(Extract_info(id, xml, 'progressive', Dict_info))
  pass

cur.close()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqljG.png), besides increasing this 2 parameter, is there a walk-around?

Comment: I cannot do any configuration changes into the DB, so that I cannot prolong the max_stand_by_streaming or max_archive_delay...... maybe I should call commit() and rollback()? But I have no idea how to incorporate here.

Comment: Also, the reason why the lock is overtime is beacasue the DB I am working on is sychronized real-time and have inserts every mins from the original DB. Anyone have a idea to deal with that? I don't mind to have a dirty data extraction as this is for a rough business decision.